# Lightning to 3.5 mm adapters only for “iOS 10.2 and below”

Tags: ios, lightning

I’ve seen quite a few Lightning to 3.5 mm headphone jack adapters that only claim compatibility with iOS 10.2 or lower. I found that very strange, since I generally expect my adapters to keep working even after I update an OS.

What does the iOS version have to do with a simple adapter like this? Does an obvious reason exist for why sellers make this claim?

Comment: Pure guess - they're not 'Made for iOS' certified… ie *'cheap cr\*p'*.

Comment: @Tetsujin Why does lack of certification equal ‘crap’?

Comment: Certification needs a specific chip in the cable. No chip, no certificate.. which means recent iOSes will reject the cable & not allow it to connect other than as a charger.

Comment: I see. Sounds more like my iPhone is being the cheap piece of crap then!

Comment: Any chance they were released at the time iOS 10.2 was the latest public version of iOS?

Comment: Other way round. So many bad cables were made & sold online as 'genuine' then just failed to actually work properly. Apple's response was to make companies get their wares actually certified as compliant. idk the details, but apparently it's not that hard/expensive to do; I can still buy certified cables from China for a buck each.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Hmm, I thought about that but no, I think the chances are slim to none considering the timeframe (3+ years ago since 10.2) combined with the probable lack of demand for this product at that time. Unless everyone rushed out to get iPhone 7s...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/ & [Wikipedia MFi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MFi_Program) - I really don't know the timeline or specifics, i just know the requirements were clamped

Comment: @Tetsujin It’s hardly the other way around if you have a working adapter one day and a non working the next. But it’s always possible to take one step further back to shift blame: Apple removed 3.5 mm, and manufacturers response was to produce cheap [...] etc. Looks like they created the situation — but it doesn’t matter. I’m just interested in whether Apple can and have bricked accessories purchased to their phones, because that will significantly affect my various future purchases. Thanks for the references!

Comment: @Tetsujin Btw, feel free to put it in an answer if you want and I’ll accept it. It sounds like the obvious reason sellers make this claim.

Comment: The certification doesn't have to coincide with the removal of the headphone socket [I didn't actually check whether it did, tbh] but the certification applies to **any** lighting connector, even if it's just a charging/USB cable & is retrospective to all lightning iDevices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has had a [Made for i*Something* (MFi)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MFi_Program) program since 2005, though initially it wasn't strictly enforced.

Anecdotally, because I can't find any announcement, only user complaints - ref [Reddit: [Request] Tweak to enable non Mfi chargers on ios 10.2](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/65w06n/request_tweak_to_enable_non_mfi_chargers_on_ios/) & others - with the introduction of iOS 10.2 the requirements became more stringent.

MFi cables & devices require a certification chip in them, licensed from Apple, otherwise they will be rejected by the iDevice.

The *implication* for cables being sold as 'works up to iOS 10.2' is that these are inferior cables - they are certainly chipless.
It's probably impossible to determine at such remove whether they were of sufficient quality to become certified, but made before the chip became compulsory & are now simply old stock, or whether they are just cheap knock-offs that would never gain certification.

[Certification](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) doesn't seem to be that difficult or expensive [It's been described as a 'tax', being a percentage of sale price] & I doubt anyone would even bother to make non-certified cables these days, as they would just be returned by any customer using a recent iOS.

I found a good blog about it on [HowToGeek: What Does Apple MFi-Certified Mean?](https://www.howtogeek.com/426208/what-does-apple-mfi-certified-mean/)

Comment: Thanks! Good info. I couldn’t make sense of the reddit post though. The actual chargers stopped working? As though implying that every single USB port on the planet where I can charge from has been certified? Sounds improbable to say the least. It’s just a 5V line. HowToGeek’s article looked trustworthy, until they started FUDing by comparing new MFi connectors with worn out non-MFi connectors, implying that the cable could cause the battery to overheat, and assuring me that all I need in order to understand that uncertified accessories “generally are trash” is Apple’s word 

Answer (score 1):

#### Lightning to 3.5mm audio jack adapters are not iOS dependent...

No matter who makes them.

This is a *hardware* solution to go from a lightning port which has no audio signaling whatsoever, to an analog connector.

[image]. [image]

Inside the Lightning to 3.5mm adapter is a DAC or *digital audio converter* that takes digital signals and converts them to analog signals.

[image]

### TL;DR

What you’re seeing is marketing verbiage that doesn’t belong as this adapter is not tied to the OS.  That said, I cannot warn strenuously enough against getting knock off (uncertified) adapters because they’re cheaper than the original then plugging them into an iPhone or iPad that can cost upwards of $1,000USD

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! A question: considering the data lines are generic, doesn’t the cable have to first negotiate the delivery of an audio stream? If so, isn’t that firmware dependent, and can’t firmware updates occur alongside OS updates? At that point, is it really exclusively a hardware solution?

Comment: Not a software issue per se, but *firmware* of the chip that handles the lightning connector (like a USB controller).  It’s unlikely to be updated with the OS. Think of it like a smarter version of the audio jack found on MacBooks. In other words, it’s all handled in hardware.

Comment: Thanks. What I was trying to ask was whether the firmware doing the negotiating on behalf of the iPhone can be updated by doing an OTA update of the OS. If so, isn’t the adapter in practice iOS dependent at that point, assuming that firmware updates are generally delivered together with a particular iOS version?

Comment: Can it?  Yes, but it’s Not likely.  Firmware updates have the potential of “bricking” things.  Looking at Apples downloads, there’s relatively few device firmware (like SMC) updates

Comment: Thanks! All it takes is one though. And I have to assume then that it actually occurred in iOS 10.